# HPE Gen10 Proliant 17.10 to 18.04 - GUI does not start - AMD Opteron X3216

Tags: 18.04, amd-graphics

Been trying to get a LTS version of Ubuntu running on my box.  When I built it, installed 17.10 and had no issues.  Upgrading to 18.04 left me with a black screen.

Did a full reinstall of 18.04 Desktop, but had to nomodeset to get to install, but again, no GUI & seemed to freeze on us.

Dropped back to 16.04.5 and same thing happened.

Tried both server editions and added the GUI.  On 16.04 we did get a GUI but it would crash after logging in for the first time, after a restart it would go to a desktop but crash shortly after.

Installed 17.10 again, all fine no problems at all.

sudo lshw -c video:

```
 description: VGA compatible controller
   product: Carrizo
   vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
   physical id: 1
   bus info: pci@0000:00:01.0
   version: 87
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm pciexpress msi vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
   configuration: driver=amdgpu latency=0
   resources: irq:38 memory:e0000000-efffffff memory:f0000000-f07fffff ioport:f000(size=256) memory:feb00000-feb3ffff memory:c0000-dffff
```

Only thing that changed between 17.10 and 18.04 was IRQ from 226 to 38.

Have tried changing the window manager to lightdm but still a black screen, I'm assuming it's a driver issue.  I've got SSH to the box.  None of the keypresses (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd> etc) do anything to get me to console.

Any ideas?

I've put the x log here:

https://pastebin.com/3nJAqEic

I think it may not be trying the VGA out, but only the two display ports?

```
[     8.641] (II) AMDGPU(0): Output DisplayPort-0 has no monitor section
[     8.641] (II) AMDGPU(0): Output DisplayPort-1 has no monitor section
[     8.641] (II) AMDGPU(0): Output DisplayPort-2 has no monitor section
[     8.642] (II) AMDGPU(0): EDID for output DisplayPort-0
[     8.642] (II) AMDGPU(0): EDID for output DisplayPort-1
[     8.642] (II) AMDGPU(0): EDID for output DisplayPort-2
[     8.642] (II) AMDGPU(0): Output DisplayPort-0 disconnected
[     8.642] (II) AMDGPU(0): Output DisplayPort-1 disconnected
[     8.642] (II) AMDGPU(0): Output DisplayPort-2 disconnected
[     8.642] (WW) AMDGPU(0): No outputs definitely connected, trying again...
[     8.642] (II) AMDGPU(0): Output DisplayPort-0 disconnected
[     8.642] (II) AMDGPU(0): Output DisplayPort-1 disconnected
[     8.642] (II) AMDGPU(0): Output DisplayPort-2 disconnected
[     8.642] (WW) AMDGPU(0): Unable to find connected outputs - setting 1024x768 initial framebuffer
```

Comment: Karel - no, sadly not.  I can't exit the GUI to terminal, just a black screen.  Only reason I know the computer is up (post boot screen) is that the SSH is available.  I've used SSH to apply the steps in the commentary, but no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this issue.  Even though the proliant gen10 has a VGA port, it also has two HPE D-Ports.

I bought a D-Port to HDMI adapter and plugged it in - success.  X was working fine.

So for some odd reason, 17.10 picks up the VGA and defaults to it, but 16.04 and 18.04 ignore the VGA completely.  Hope this helps someone else.